# autocd if and only if the path is a collection of `../`

Tags: zsh, cd

I'm using zsh & I've aliased `..` to `cd ..`. I want zsh to `cd` to a path if and only if the typed out path is a repetition of `..` or `../`.

The following should auto-`cd`:

```
..
../
../../../../
../../..
```

These should not auto-`cd`:

```
../../mydir
mydir
/dir
```

How can I configure zsh (and maybe bash) to auto-`cd` like so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'DEBUG' [trap](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) to intercept commands, e.g. to emulate 'autocd':

```
TRAPDEBUG() {
    if [[ "$ZSH_DEBUG_CMD" =~ ^\\.\\.(/\\.\\.)*/?$ ]]; then
        : "Emulate autocd"
        cd "$ZSH_DEBUG_CMD"
        echo "Now in $PWD"
        : "Cancel the original command"
        set -e
    fi
}
```